# How I should respond on which command person answer on Telegram Bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

My bot has some commands, for example: `/change_info` and `/music`.
When person use '/music' command, bot shows keyboard which offers an option: add music.
Person tap "**add music**", after this, in chat history show "add music" and next message will be from user where he should type him music, for example "**Rap**". 
So, I have question: how I must understand via code, that user type "Rap" for question about /music, not about /change_info command? 
I need to take last bot message and if it's was /music, i should process it command as music? But i think it's very bad option. Can you help me please with my question and sorry for my english:)

Comment: You should have states for your users, search for a state-machine in your preferred language.